# Apache CXF how to handle date conversion xsd:date to java.util.Date without timezone

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, cxf

Here is my problem with CXF. I have a SOAP1.2 service written in CXF. The service isn't complicated, it basically puts an XML int DB (Oracle 11.x). All the dates in WSDL are defined as xsd:date.

I have following jaxb bindings defined

```
    <jxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xsd:date"
        parseMethod="org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.parseDate"
        printMethod="org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.printDate" />
```

And the Adapter class which utilizes these is as follows

```
public class Adapter2
extends XmlAdapter<String, Date>
{


public Date unmarshal(String value) {
    return (org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.parseDate(value));
}

public String marshal(Date value) {
    return (org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.printDate(value));
}
}
```

Since cxf..runtime.DataTypeAdapter always yields java.util.Date, there is always a time added which in turn problem for the Oracle, because Oracle's native procedure for xml validation yields error when it encounters date with time. (Change DB settings is not an option).

**What libraries/classes can use to marshal/unmrashal xsd:date to dates without a time?** Or do I have to write my own class extending the XmlAdapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've came up with this

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter;

public class DateTypeAdapterWrapper {

    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";

    public static Date parseDate(String value) {
        return (DataTypeAdapter.parseDate(value));
    }

    public static String printDate(Date value) {
        String tmp = DataTypeAdapter.printDate(value);
        if(tmp == null) {
            return null;
        }
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        return dateFormat.format(value);
    }
}
```

No doubt, there is a better to this, but here it is.